# In scala map, filter,grouby are functions or methods

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I need to understand one basic idea.

In scala, we have map,filter,groupBy  etc..

Are they functions? or Are they methods?

Comment: Short answer: everything which is defined with `def` is a method in Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are methods. See, e.g. the [`scala.collection.GenTraversableLike.map`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableLike@map[B](f:A=>B):scala.collection.GenTraversable[B]) method.

There aren't really functions in the Scala Core Language.

Basically, the support for functions in Scala is similar to Java: any object which has a method called `apply`, can be used as a "function". There are a number of traits in the Scala Standard Library, called `Function0[+R]`, [`Function1[-T1, +R]`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function1), [`Function2[-T1, -T2, +R]`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function2), `Function3[-T1, -T2, -T3, +R]`, etc. which can be instantiated using special literal syntax like this:

```
val fn = (i: Int, j: Int) => i + j
```

There are two ideas what it means to be a "function" in Scala:

- the narrow one: an instance of one of the `FunctionN` traits, or
- the general one: any object which has an `apply` method.

`map`, `filter`, `groupBy`, are neither, they aren't even objects. They are methods.

Answer (score 0):

Those are higher order functions that many Scala classes provide and can be used to compose other functions

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html

This higher order functions may be methods if (from Scala doc) "A method is a function that is a member of some class, trait, or singleton object."